# Proving a property of a compact, totally disconnected metric space.

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology, analysis, metric-spaces, compactness

Here is the question:

If $X$ is a compact metric space that is totally disconnected, then for each $r > 0$ and each $x \in X,$ there is a clopen set $U$ such that $x \in U$ and $U \subseteq B_{r}(x).$

**Definition:**

A topological space $X$ is totally disconnected if for any two distinct points $x,y \in X,$ there is a separation $X = U \cup V$ of $X$ with $x \in U $ and $y \in V.$

**Definition:**

A subset of a topological space is clopen if it is both closed and open.

**My questions are: **

1-I was given a hint to show that $X-B_{r}(x)$ is compact, which I do not know how to show, so any help in that direction will be appreciated.

2- How to show the existence of such clopen set $U$?

Comment: Your definition of totally disconnected is not correct.  What you wrote is the definition of totally separated.  Totally disconnected means that all connected components are singletons.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For 1, $X - B_r(x)$ is the complement of an open set $B_r(x)$, which makes it closed. Since it is a closed subspace of a compact space $X$, it is compact too.

For 2, for any point $y \in X - B_r(x)$, you can use total disconnectedness to find disjoint open sets $U_y$ and $V_y$ such that $X = U_y \cup V_y$, and $x \in U_y$, with $y \in V_y$. These sets are complementary, and since both are open, they are both closed as well. Note that the $V_y$s cover every point $y \in X - B_r(x)$, which is compact, so a finite subcover must exist...

Are you able to finish it from there?

Comment: I will try to finish it and if I have any problem I will write in a comment here. thank you!

Comment: Sounds like a plan. I, however, am off to sleep, so there might be a delay. :-)

Comment: Could you give me more details about the completion? what is the importance of $X - B_{r}(x)$ having a finite cover?

Comment: What does the question want to teach me?

Comment: @Happy The question is mostly just an exercise in using compactness and total disconnectedness, and wants you to get practice in using these properties to prove something. As for your other question, finding a finite subcover from the $V_y$s produces a finite set $V_{y_1}, \ldots, V_{y_n}$ which are open and cover $X - B_r(x)$. Note that $U_{y_1} \cap \ldots \cap U_{y_n}$ is open and its complement, $V_{y_1} \cup \ldots V_{y_n}$ is open, and contains $X - B_r(x)$.

Comment: So what is our $U$ (the clopen set that we want to prove its existence)?

Comment: I got a hint that this exercise implies that the topology on a totally disconnected space $X$ has a basis consisting entirely of clopen sets ..... but I do not know how this exercise implies this .... could you explain for me please? ..... Also, is the converse true?

Comment: The $U$ is $U_{y_1} \cap \ldots \cap U_{y_n}$. It's open, and its complement is open, so it's closed. It also is contained in $X - B_r(x)$. As for the converse, what do you mean? Does the existence of a clopen subset of every ball imply that the space is totally disconnected? Yes it does. Does it imply it's compact? Not necessarily. Does it imply the space has a metric? Absolutely not.

Comment: The converse that is meant is " is it true that a metric space with a basis of clopen sets is necessarily totally disconnected?
"